# Unable to automatically remount webdav shared drive on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, alfresco, shared, webdav

I am trying to automatically mount a shared drive pointing to Webdav on a Yosemite mac. I am correctly able to connect, access Webdav, and copy files into the repository. I am also able to set the shared drive as a login item.

The problem comes when I reboot, it delivers an error. When I read the console, it says: "webdavfs_agent: Webdav FS authentication credentials are being sent insecurely to: http://address", then "webdavfs_agent: network_mount: network_stat returned error 2". I am still able to connect by clicking "connect to server" then selecting the saved connection, I do not have to reinput credentials or change the address in any way.

Replacing http with https does not allow me to connect at all. Deleting and recreating the credentials in keychain had no effect, and I've tried deleting and recreating the login item every way I can think of (pointing to the root repository, further up the directory chain, further down, etc).

Any ideas what is going wrong? This is Alfresco's Webdav hosted remotely on AWS, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by creating an applescript to mount WebDAV then setting the script as a login item. Here is the script:

```
property username : "username"
property pass : "password"

tell application "Finder"
    try
        mount volume "http://" & username & ":" & pass & "@ipaddress/alfresco/webdav/Sites/site/documentLibrary"
    end try
end tell
```